# How to get an image name using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's says I have :

```
<img src='static/images/banner/blue.jpg' />
```

Using jQuery, how could I get the `blue` data ?

If I use `$('img').attr('src')`, I can get the whole URI. In that case, what is the best way to remove the extension and all the path ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a couple gotcha here- local files may use the other slash ('\') in the pathname, and some filenames can have hash or search tails defined, or not have an extension.

```
String.prototype.filename=function(extension){
    var s= this.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    s= s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
    return extension? s.replace(/[?#].+$/, ''): s.split('.')[0];
}

console.log($('img').attr('src').filename());
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var src = $('img').attr('src').split('/');
var file = src[src.length - 1];
```

Should work

Answer (score 12):

Just split the string:

```
var src = $('img').attr('src'); // "static/images/banner/blue.jpg"
var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["static","images","banner","blue.jpg"]
var file = tarr[tarr.length-1]; // "blue.jpg"
var data = file.split('.')[0];  // "blue"
```

Comment: Just a sidenote that this example will return eg: `summer` from an image called `summer.2013.jpg`

Answer (score 11):

Regex will be your best friend here...

`var filename = fullUri.replace( /^.*?([^\/]+)\..+?$/, '$1' );`

Comment: Now it's perfect, you just forgot to escape `/`, Should be `( /^.*?([^\/]+)\..+?$/, '$1' );`

Answer (score 5):

Say we have:

```
<img src="path/to/awesome/image/foobar.jpg" />
```

Here's what we do to extract the file name:

```
Array.prototype.filename = function() {
   var tmp = this.split('/');
   return tmp[tmp.length-1].match(/(.*)\.[\w]+$/)[1];
});

$('img').attr('src').filename();
```

Result:

```
console.log(name); // foobar
```

Comment: **I would not suggest that one**: what in the case of `summer.2013.jpg` ?? the filename is not `summer` but `summer.2013`

Answer (score 2):

```
src = $('img').attr('src');
src_array = src.split('/');
src = src_array[src.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var src= $('img').attr('src');

var name = src.match(/static\/images\/banner\/(.*)\.jpg/)[1];
```